# Sintaxis c# en WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

Tags: c#, .net

NET6.0 ha introducido nuevas clases y métodos; en [WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebApplication.cs)  se puede encontrar el siguiente código

```
public static WebApplicationBuilder CreateBuilder(string[] args) =>
    new(new() { Args = args });
```

- Qué es lo que está haciendo el new(new...)?
- Crea una instancia de?
- Es una nueva sintaxis de c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esa sintaxis no es *nueva* ni *exclusiva* de .Net 6.0, está disponible desde C# 9.0 que fue introducido en .Net 5.0.

Simplemente permite crear una instancia si se conoce el tipo de resultado esperado de antemano. En vez de decir, por ejemplo:

```cs
List<int> lista = new List<int>();
```

Puedes hacerlo con:

```cs
List<int> lista = new();
```

Para el caso en el que se basa tu pregunta, tienes:

```cs
public static WebApplicationBuilder CreateBuilder(string[] args) =>
    new(new() { Args = args });
```

que es básicamente crear o inicializar una instancia de [`WebAplicationBuilder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplicationbuilder?view=aspnetcore-6.0), que espera una lista (`Array`) de argumentos de tipo `string` como parámetro y dicha lista la estás creando precisamente usando:

```cs
new() { Args = args }
```

Para mayor información puedes consultar la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator)